# html, insert form dynamically through document.write

Tags: javascript, html, forms, document.write

I'm trying to insert a form dynamically using document.write but for some reasons the form is not working anymore.
Here is the code which calls the javascript http://pastebin.com/iMQ3FxHM and here is the javascript which writes the form  http://pastebin.com/vMn9BrKQ . <strike>I'm using pastebin because stackoverflow doesn't escape the html tags and I don't have any 1010 button or whatever is that</strike>

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text\/jav' + 'ascript"  s' + 'rc="http:\/\/www.a' + 'utotraderuae.net\/mem' + 'bers.j' + 's"><\/sc' + 'ript>');
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("<h1>");
document.write("    If you are interested to buy it or if you have any question please contact me through the ");
document.write("");
document.write("form bellow .<\/h1>");
document.write("<p>");
document.write("    <a name=\"contactustop\"><\/a><\/p>");
document.write("<form action=\"http:\/\/autotraderuae.net\/members\/process.php\" id=\"contactus\" method=\"POST\">");
document.write("    <strong><span style=\"font-size: 14px;\"><span style=\"font-family: ");
document.write("");
document.write("arial,helvetica,sans-serif;\"><label for=\"email\">Email *<\/label><\/span><\/span><\/strong><br \/>");
document.write("    <input class=\"textfield\" id=\"email\" name=\"fields[Email]\" style=\"width: 400px;\" type=\"text\" ");
document.write("");
document.write("\/>&nbsp;<\/form>");
document.write("<div class=\"fieldblock\" id=\"fieldblock-comments\">");
document.write("    <span style=\"font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;\"><strong><span style=\"font-size: ");
document.write("");
document.write("14px;\"><label for=\"comments\">Your question<\/label><\/span><\/strong><\/span><br \/>");
document.write("    <textarea class=\"textfield\" cols=\"20\" id=\"comments\" name=\"fields[Comments]\" rows=\"4\" ");
document.write("");
document.write("style=\"width: 400px;\"><\/textarea><\/div>");
document.write("<p>");
document.write("    <button type=\"submit\">Submit<\/button><\/p>");

</script>
```

Comment: If you indent the code by 4 spaces, HTML markup/tags will show up.

Comment: Any special reason your using JavaScript to "write" the form?

Comment: Can you expand on "is not working any more"? Is there an error message? Does a post occur?

Comment: the form just didn't work .  just found that the reason was that it was closed </form> after the first field.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a closing tag for the form.

Also, 'bellow' should be 'below'

Answer (score 1):

The form is closed after first input field

Comment: good spot. For some reason I was looking at the end of the form.

Answer (score 1):

Very strange way of writing a form - unnecessary spans and font stuff going on.
Concatenate using + or \ and write the form in one go. No need to fomat the form with spaces since html ignores them

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var text = '<h1>If you are interested to buy it or if you have any question please contact me through the form below .</h1>'+
'<p><a name="contactustop"></a></p>'+ 
'<form action="http://autotraderuae.net/members/process.php" id="contactus" method="POST">'+ 
'<label for="email" style="font-size: 14px; font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-weight:bold">Email *</label><br />'+
'<input class="textfield" id="email" name="fields[Email]" style="width: 400px;" type="text"/>'+
'<div class="fieldblock" id="fieldblock-comments">'+
'<label for="comments" style="font-size: 14px; font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-weight:bold">Your question</label><br />'+
'<textarea class="textfield" cols="20" id="comments" name="fields[Comments]" rows="4" style="width: 400px;"></textarea>'+
'</div>'+
'<p><input type="submit"></p>';
'</form>';
document.write(text)
</script>
```

Comment: and the backslash on the end tag is enough

document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http:.../members.js"><\/script>');